# 16 bit ms-dos subsystem error while creating android emulator

Tags: android, windows-7, android-virtual-device

**-** Everything was working fine till the electricity went off.

**-** After the electricity came back and i switched on the computer, i am getting this weird error as i am trying to start or create the Android Virtual Device in the Android Virtual Device Manager.

**Error image:**

[image]

Can anyone please let me know the reason for such an occurrence or any possible way to restore this back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like some part of your 16-Bit subsystem was corrupted. I found a quite comprehensive troubleshooting-guide here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q196453

If that doesn't help have a look here and try whatever these guys found:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5466e39-29b2-4667-96c4-6bacd8a397d4/the-ntvdm-cpu-has-encountered-an-illegal-instruction-error-message-pops-up-when-installing-visual?forum=vssourcecontrol